# java rabbitmq timeout for server consumer

Tags: java, timeout, rabbitmq, consumer

I am doing an RPC implementation with java and rabittmq.

I would like to be able to stop the consumer with a timeout, this means after the timeout for the consumer to process is over, I want message to send a response message to the client to notify that the consumer was not able to process the request.

For example if my consumer for some reason hangs then the timeout will notice and send an error message to the client.